# CSS & HTML // Only want background to be on body not divs too

Tags: html, css, image, background

Alright so basically. I need my code to have the name at the top and the background be a picture of a bride. When I do

```
*{
font-family: Open Sans;
background-image: url(assets/photos/bride);
background-size: cover;
```

It works but also becomes the background to my divs

```
    <body>

    <div class="menu_button">
        <img src="">
    </div>

    <div class="text">
        <h1 id="name">RANDOM NAME</h1>
        <p id="kicker"><strong>DESIGNER // PHOTOGRAPHER // JOURNALIST</strong></p>
    </div>

</body>
```

So I get a weird broken affect
[image]

Comment: Well yeah, you're saying "make `*` have this", and `*` is a wildcard selector for every single element. Use `body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The * selector in CSS applies to every element in the DOM.

Use the body selector to apply the background image to just the body.

```
* {
    font-family: Open Sans;
}
body {
    background-image: url(assets/photos/bride);
    background-size: cover;
}
```